# smpp client in java

Tags: java, smpp

I have a project which consists of the delivery of an sms containing the national identification number of a user upon request. This request will be in the form of an sms. Say for instance a client sends an sms to the mobile operator, my app would retrieve the national id and communicates it to the mobile operator which would send it the client. I wish to achieve this through java smpp. I have downloaded and installed SMPPSim but i don't know what is the next step. I need to simulate the sending and reception of the two sms.

Comment: Hi Paul, I did a quick google search and found this: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sending-sms-with-smpp-kannel-and-java

I think it's a good starting point and might help you get in the right direction on your project.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed kannel as well the smsc simulator SMPPSim and also gone through some of the documentation. Now my problem is, how can i simulate the reception of an sms? Say for instance a client sends 'nidn 5', i want to be able to take 5 and process it in a servlet to retrieve the associated national identification number.